# React state change does not result in a rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-state

I'm using [React Infinite Scroller](https://github.com/danbovey/react-infinite-scroller#readme) to render a list of posts.

My load more results function is called 3 times and therefore the result is updated three times (can be seen with a console.log)

I render the posts with:

```
{results.map((result) => (
    <Widget data={result} key={result.id} />
))}
```

This updates the result the first two times, but when the state changes for the third time, it doesn't render any more results.

My full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";
import LoadingIndicator from "./loading";
import { request } from "../communication";

const InfiniteResults = ({ endpoint, widget }) => {
  let [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  let [hasMoreResults, setHasMoreResults] = useState(true);

  const Widget = widget;

  function loadMoreResults(page) {
    // prevent from making more requests while waiting for the other one to complete
    setHasMoreResults(false);

    request
      .get(endpoint, {
        offset: page * 10,
      })
      .then(function gotResults(response) {
        const data = response.data;

        const resultsCopy = results;
        data.results.forEach(function saveResultToState(result) {
          resultsCopy.push(result);
        });
        setResults(resultsCopy);
        console.log(resultsCopy);
        console.log(results);

        if (!data.next) {
          setHasMoreResults(false);
        } else {
          setHasMoreResults(true);
        }
      });
  }

  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      pageStart={-1}
      loadMore={loadMoreResults}
      hasMore={hasMoreResults}
      loader={<p key={0}>Loading...</p>}
    >
      {results.map((result) => {
        console.log("rerender");
        return <Widget data={result} key={result.id} />;
      })}
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
};

export default InfiniteResults;
```

Comment: You are not updating the state correctly: instead of 'copying' the `results` state (it won't actually copy like that), you should call `setResults` with a function that takes the previous results as an argument: `setResults(prevResults => prevResults.concat(data.results));` Could you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your state update:

```js
const resultsCopy = results;
data.results.forEach(function saveResultToState(result) {
  resultsCopy.push(result);
);
setResults(resultsCopy);
```

When you do `const resultsCopy = results;`, you're not actually copying the array; you're just referring to the same array by another name. That means that when you start adding elements to it, you are adding them directly to the one controlled by React's `useState` hook. All state updates should be done through the `setState` (`setResults` in your case) function that `useState` returns.

To perform an update on the previous state, the best way to do that is to call the `setResults` function with a function as an argument, that takes the previous state as its own argument. This ensures that the state updates are sequential (each update happens after the previous one was completed).

```js
setResults(prevState => prevState.concat(data.results));
// or
setResults(function (prevState) {
  return prevState.concat(data.results);
});
```

Here I have also made use of the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function that combines two arrays into one and returns the result. That way you are not updating the previous state with the `push` calls.

Comment: You should add `const resultsCopy = [...results]` optiom, as it the way to shallow copy in js, anyhow great answer

Comment: @HagaiHarari I was going to, but decided not to, as that can still result in inconsistencies: as you said, it's only a shallow copy (not a problem here, but mutating an array's objects would be), and ensuring sequentiality of state updates is important when loading pages of data one after another.